# How can I pass $title a node variable to html.tpl.php?

Tags: theming

I'm looking to use the variable $title in my html.tpl.php file. How can I do this?

I would like to just write a bit of php like so:

```
<?php print $title ?>
```

So is a preprocess function needed? TPLNAME_preprocess_html() { ??? something like that?

I would like to reference this question here which got me thinking, what is the proper way?

[Helpful Question That I Saw](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6956870/get-node-variable-in-html-tpl-php-drupal-7/6957622#6957622)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

```
// template.php
function THEMENAME_preprocess_html(&$vars) {
  $vars['title'] = 'my title';
}

// html.tpl.php
echo $title;
```

http://drupal.org/node/223430

Comment: Would this also work for the current node being viewed?

Comment: hook_preprocess_html called on all pages. If you edit vars only node view page - use hook_preprocess_node and template node.tpl.php

Comment: What I am trying to do is pass the current nodes title to a variable within my html.tpl.php file. Does that make sense? Thanks again for your reply.

Answer (score 6):

If you are wanting $title to be the node title of the current page (if it is a node page), which you mentioned in a comment above, you can do this in your theme's template.php:

```
/**
 * Override or insert variables into the html templates.
 */
function THEMENAME_preprocess_html(&$vars) {
  if ($node = menu_get_object()) {
    $vars['title'] = check_plain($node->title);
  }
}
```